# Why doesn't the calling assembly show up in the current app domain in c#?

Tags: c#, reflection, mono, .net-assembly

I'm using MonoDevelop and I have one library project and one NUnit project in the same solution. The NUnit project references the library and contains my tests. Some of the behavior that I would like to test involves inspecting types and methods in loaded assemblies. I tried using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` but neither the library nor the NUnit tests are in any of these assemblies. I'm sure that I'm misunderstanding something here but I expected to find them both here. I can get the library by calling `AppDomain.GetExecutingAssembly()` and the tests by calling `AppDomain.GetCallingAssembly()` but the latter is not totally reliable based on what I've read (because of possible inlining for one thing).

Could somebody please clear up for me why the executing and calling assemblies aren't in the current app domain? Is it possible to loop over a collection of assemblies that would include both of these? I've found [an example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jackg/archive/2007/06/11/enumerating-appdomains.aspx) of looping over all app domains but it requires mscoree which is not available in MonoDevelop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the documentation of NUnit: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Assembly-Isolation the assemblies are loaded into different AppDomains. So with
`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` you will never get your assemblies.

Comment: This answers the first half of my question, but do you have any idea about the second? Is it possible to access other app domains without using mscoree?

Comment: I'm afraid there is currently no possibility to enumerate all loaded AppDomains in the Mono environment.